# Resolvent operator of a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $X$ is a Banach space and $T:X\rightarrow X$ is a bounded linear operator, then how to show that $\|R_\lambda$(T)$\| \rightarrow 0$, as $|\lambda| \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Assuming $R_{\lambda}(T)=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$, then what is wrote is not correct. Did you mean "as $|\lambda|\rightarrow\infty$"?

Answer (score 3):

For $|\lambda| > \|T\|$,
$$
   (T-\lambda I)^{-1} = -\frac{1}{\lambda} (I-\frac{1}{\lambda}T)^{-1}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}T^{n} \\
         \|(T-\lambda I)^{-1}\| \le \frac{1}{|\lambda|}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\|T\|^n}{|\lambda|^n}=\frac{1}{|\lambda|}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\|T\|}{|\lambda|}}=\frac{1}{|\lambda|-\|T\|}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $T-\lambda I = -\lambda( I - \lambda^{-1}T$, it is clear that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible for all $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|$ large enough, i.e., $|\lambda|>\|T\|$.

Take $x,z$ such that $(T-\lambda I)x=z$. Then
$$
\|R_\lambda(T)z\|=\|x\| =\| \lambda^{-1}(z-Tx)\|\le |\lambda|^{-1}(\|z\|+\|T\|\cdot\|x\|).
$$
If $|\lambda| >2 \|T\|$ then it follows
$$
\frac12\|x\|\le (1-\lambda^{-1}\|T\|)\|x\| \le |\lambda|^{-1}\|z\|,
$$
which is the wanted inequality.